# commonJS - does it have a public property?

Tags: commonjs

I had an interesting read of a discussion of commonJS - foun

http://smorgasbork.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=132

However, it didn't answer the main question i had - is it possible to have a public member in a generic commonJS object?

That is, not with the whole fancy object created (which the tutorial goes into refreshing detail with) but just, you know, generic style.

How to declare, if it is static or not etc - anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then **yes**.

```javascript
function MyClass(options) {
    // something like a constructor in java
    this.myProperty = 'foo'; // instance property
}

MyClass.prototype.doSometing(what)
    // this is an instance method (because of prototype, this is generated for each instance, can have a reference to `this`)
}

MyClass.doSomethingElse(andWhat)
    // this is a static method, which is not available for an instantiated object (only via MyClass.doSometingElse();)
}

MyClass.staticProperty = 'bar'; // static property;

module.exports = MyClass;
```

I hope that this is the thing you wanted to know. They are all publicly available. Not possible is to create a private static property since these properties are always public. Also a private instance property is usually not private or not a real property. It's simply a local variable which only can be accessed within the function where it is defined. If you can access it via `this`, then it is also publicly available.

---

off topic: before exporting this module you could create one instance and export the instance. This would create something like a singleton in Java. So whenever you request this module you will get the same instance:

```javascript
MyClass = new MyClass();
module.exports = MyClass;
```

But this will remove all static references since MyClass would be an instance in this case.